# VBA code to Copy Excel range $A$1, Paste into Saved WordDocument (Not New Document), SaveAs that document Filename As another Excel range $A$2

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, copy, paste

Working with both Word and Excel macros, I am trying to copy from excel then paste it into MSWord then give that Word file a new name as another excel cell value.

I want to create an Excel VBA Code to:

- copy cell A1 from excel,
- open a saved word document,
- paste copied value in that document,
- save as document and give the filename as the value of cell A2.

I tried to create Four Macros for each step, and one more to call them at once.

```
Sub Steps1234() 
               'Call Macros from Excel and Word
    Call Step1
    Call Step2
    Call Step3
    Call Step4
End Sub

Sub Step1() 
               'Copy From Excel
End Sub

Sub Step2() 
               'Open Saved WordDocument
End Sub

Sub Step3() 
               'Paste Copied Value into a word document
End Sub

Sub Step4() 
               'SaveAs WordDocument as ExcelCellValue
End Sub
```

I created a macro in excel then I created a macro in word. But do not know the last step.

```
Sub Step1() 
               'Copy From Excel cell Value A1
    Range("$A$1").Copy
End Sub


Sub Step2() 
               'Open Saved WordDocument
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\FolderXYZ\"
    Documents.Open FileName:="FileABC.docx", ConfirmConversions:= _
        False, ReadOnly:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False, PasswordDocument:="", _
        PasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, WritePasswordDocument:="", _
        WritePasswordTemplate:="", Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, XMLTransform:=""
End Sub

Sub Step3() 
               'Paste Copied Value into WordDocument
    Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
End Sub

Sub Step4() 
               'SaveAs WordDocument as ExcelCellValue A2
    Don’t know exactly what to do.
End Sub
```

Thank You

Comment: Are you asking about all four steps or only the fourth one which you indicate that you don't know how to do. Have you verified any of the steps already? Did you do a search of already existing questions / answers? Entering "[vba] copy from excel to word" in the search box gives 911 results.

Comment: Hello Tom, Thanks for the suggestion. I tried searching the same; some of the codes do the work separately. But want to do the whole code at once.  I am sure that many things are missing to get the task done.  Any help on this is much appreciated. Thank You.